# MATLAB - Show group belongingness of data points?

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset that can be divided into either 3 groups, `grp_A1`, `grp_A2`, and `grp_A3`, by criteria `A` or meanwhile 3 **different** groups, `grp_B1`, `grp_B2`, and `grp_B3`, by criteria `B`.

I wish to visualize this using MATLAB. The desired visualization should contain circles enclosing the data points according to the points' membership.

For example, consider a simple dataset containing 4 points

```
[pt1 pt2 pt3 pt4]
```

By criteria `A`, `pt1` and `pt2` belong to `grp_A1`, pt3 belongs to  `grp_A2`, and pt4 belongs to `grp_A3`. So one red (red for criteria `A`) circle encloses `pt1` and `pt2`, a second red circle encloses `pt3`, and a third red circle encloses `pt4`.

Yet by criteria `B`, instead of being in the same group as `pt2`, `pt1` is in the same group as `pt3`. Hence, there should be one blue (blue for criteria `B`) enclosing `pt1` and `pt3`, one enclosing `pt2`, and one enclosing `pt4`.

How should I do this in MATLAB?

## Update

What makes the problem complicated is that my data points are high-dimensional, meaning that I will also have to figure out a way to "reasonably" present them in 2D. By "reasonably", I mean I should sort of arrange them in such a way that the circles do not look messy.

Answer (score 0):

Introducing circles into the figure will probably make it messy. Maybe, use three different colors for criteria A, and three different shapes for criteria B, and plot them over your data